# Adding to ngnix configuration using .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-location, ebextensions

I'm trying to add two simple things to nginx.conf which work fine until I deploy a new version on ELB, which is expected, so I know I need to use .ebextensions to do this but I either get an error saying "null values are not allowed in templates" or it just doesn't work.

This is my file which is in /.ebextensions/custom.config

```
files: 
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf": 
    content: |
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        server {
            location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }
        }
```

Simply trying to change the max upload size and adding the location info in to work with Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

There are **indentation** issues. it should be (note `content`):

```
files: 
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf": 
        content: |
            client_max_body_size 100M;
            server {
                location / {
                    index index.php index.html index.htm;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                }
            }
```

For form of the `files`, check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files).

There could be other reasons why it fails, can't tell from the short question. But the indentation is definitely one of the reasons you have problems though.